# Is it possible to customize the color of TabCloseButton icon in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

`VSCode version 1.16`

When i have unsaved changes in a file, the dot in the tab file's name is not really visible as seen below.

[image: image of pending changes in a file]

I'd like to highlight it somehow (e.g. to change its color). I inspected the dot element via `Dev tools` in VSCode and it has a `ciass` of `action-label icon close-editor-action` but i am not sure how could I implement the `CSS` into editors' customization..

I know about `workbench.colorCustomizations` settings but i have not found any documentation about this particular little thing.
The only customizable setting of `tabCloseButton` is changing its position but not its visual.

Does anybody know how could this be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css).

For instance: changing the entire unsaved tab:

```css
.tab.dirty {
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 8px,
      #465298 9px
    );
}
```

Or changing close icon:

```css
.tab.dirty .close-editor-action {
    background: #465298 !important; /* here could be some inline image*/
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what Custom CSS and JS Loader does, how it works, or where to modify files, and the extension info is slim. I'm assuming it's a way to change the look and operations of VSCode, but I wouldn't even know where to change the css you're showing here. Where would I do that?

Comment: You create a new `custom.css` file somewhere on the system. Then enter the path in the  url format at the `vscode_custom_css.imports` setting. It's all in the https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css#getting-started section.